# How can I refresh a fancybox popup?

Tags: asp.net, fancybox, refresh, pageload

`enter code here`I have a fancybox popup that has the list of cities on it, and a textbox. Once a user enters another city name into the textbox and clicks "Save", I am able to save the new city into the database, but how can I also reload just the popup, so that the new city appears in the list as well?
My popup is an ASPX page, and all I would have to do is somehow execute the Page_Load event, so that it would display the datagrid with all the cities.

Is there any way I can do that? Somehow reload the popup? PLEASE HELP!!!

Here is the fancybox code that opens my popup:

```
$(document).ready(
                function () {
                    $("#location").fancybox({
                        onClosed: function () {
                            __doPostBack('BodyContent', '');
                        },
                        ajax : {
                        'cache': false,
                        'titlePosition': 'inside',
                        'overlayShow': true,
                        'overlayColor': '#000',
                        'transitionIn': 'elastic',
                        'transitionOut': 'elastic'
                      }
            });

        });
```

Comment: I guess your function is not well formed, you shouldn't put the fancybox options inside the ajax call. As far as I can tell, your function only binds fancybox to the selector "#location" but it doesn't trigger fancybox (unless there are other parts of your code you are not publishing here)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, you should do this: within the server event that gets executed when you close the popup, make sure that you rebind the grid (feed it with the updated data and call its DataBind method again.

Comment: No, I want to reload my popup, not my parent. I want my popup to re-execute the page_load event

Comment: so, after the postback, you want the popup to show immediately after the page loads? I see that `__doPostBack('BodyContent', '');` statement that looks like it gets executed when the popup closes, so my conclusion is that a POST happens? Or, is that an AJAX call?

Comment: That is for when I close the popup, but if i don't close the popup I want to be able to refresh my popup by clicking on a button or a hyperlink (that is on the popup) for example.

Comment: Well, couldn't you add HTML that relates to the new record that you just sent to the server? so, when AddCity ajax call returns, add HTML for the new city (it's probably a TR element and a few TD's).

Comment: I didn't think about it like that, I suppose it could be done.... But still - is there a way to simply refresh an open popup? There has to be a way, wouldn't you think?

Comment: If the popup is built based on what markup exists on the page, then you'd have to update that markup (via js or page-refresh) and then close-open the popup. If page refresh is your choice, then you'd have to render some js variable, based on which you'd re-open the popup.